# iTunes won't play through Bluetooth when using a WiFi connection

Tags: macos, itunes, bluetooth

So iTunes and my Bluetooth speaker works fine with songs in my library and songs on Apple Music, but if I go to the radio tab and play an Apple Music radio station or play any internet Stream, it switches to my Macbook's computer speakers. This happens regularly, and has been happening for a long time. I can replicate it reliably.

Note, I can play radio stations that are not live. The issue only occurs with stations that are streamed over a WiFi connection.

Any idea why Bluetooth won't play Apple Radio stations?

[image]

Comment: I could find no information that this is a limitation of iTunes Radio.